# why $\det(I_n)$ is $1$

Tags: linear-algebra

I use mechanically the notion that $\det(I_n)=1.$
I tried to analyse it with the definition and now I have a doubt.

$$\det (I_n)=\sum_{p \in \sigma_n} \varepsilon (p)\cdot a_{1p(1)}\cdot a_{2p(2)} \cdots a_{np(n)}=\varepsilon (1)\cdot a_{11}\cdot a_{22}\cdots a_{nn}$$

with $a_{11}=a_{22}=\cdots=a_{nn}=1$ and

$\varepsilon (p)=(-1)^h$ where $h$ is the number of transposition in which we can decompose the permutation $p$
than I think it is $n-1$.

My question is how can $\varepsilon (p)=(-1)^h$ be always egual to $1$ if $n-1$ can assume an odd value or an even value depending on $n$?

Comment: Alternate method: Determinant of a diagonal matrix is product of its diagonal entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should the formula not be:

$$\det(I_n) = \sum_{p\in\sigma_n} \epsilon(p) a_{1,p(1)}a_{2,p(2)}a_{3,p(3)}\dots a_{n,p(n)}$$

All terms in the sum will be zero because at least one factor $a_{i,p(i)}$ in it is off-diagonal, except when $p$ is the identical map (trivial permutation) which leads to one single nonzero term. But what is the sign, or parity, of this permutation?

Comment: It should be 0 transposition, isn't it?

Comment: @Anne Yes. That trivial permutation can be seen as 0 transpositions, and so you get $(-1)^h=(-1)^0=+1$, and your proposition that $\det(I_n)$ is always equal to positive one, has been proved.

Answer (score 3):

First, once you have used the fact that $a_{ij}$ is zero unless i= j (which you have since you write "$a_{11}*a_{22}*\cdot\cdot\cdot*a_{nn}$" rather than the general "$a_{1p(1)}*a_{2p(2)}*\cdot\cdot\cdot*a_{np(n)}$") you **no longer** have a sum over all permutations.  The only permutation that does not have a "0" term in the product is the **identity** permutation and its $\epsilon(p)$ is 1.